# Magento update inventory with REST

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I Followed the instruction of this page http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/inventory.html#RESTAPI-Resource-StockItems-HTTPMethod-PUT-stockitems--id and I have this code:

```
$oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
$resourceUrl = $apiUrl.'/stockitems/429';
$productData = json_encode(array(
        'qty'           => 982,
        'is_in_stock'   => 1
    ));
$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $productData, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $headers);
print_r($oauthClient->getLastResponseInfo());
```

But I get the return

```
[message:protected] => Invalid auth/bad request (got a 401, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
```

I tried with XML like this:

```
$oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
$resourceUrl = $apiUrl.'/stockitems/429';
$productData = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <magento_api>
        <qty>99</qty>
    </magento_api>';
$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'text/xml');
$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $productData, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $headers);
print_r($oauthClient->getLastResponseInfo());
```

and I get the error:

```
[message:protected] => Invalid auth/bad request (got a 405, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: looks like the authentication is failing, did you manage to authenticate?

Comment: The authentication goes smoothly and I get everything else so I'm correctly logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to update item's quantity is to call the /products/:id API, method = PUT, with the following payload:

```
{"stock_data" : {"qty" : "123"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using POST instead of PUT. HTTP Post is used for creating items in Magento, but if you  update an item (or inventory, image, whatever) by id you have to use PUT.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you assigned to your admin user REST role.

Configuring Permissions Step By Step:

- System -> Web Services -> REST - Roles -> Create new role
- System -> Web Services -> REST - Consumers -> Create a Consumer -> Copy Key & Secret to use in your App
- System -> Permissions -> Your User -> REST Role -> Select and Save your Role